# CMake doesn't find library in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/

Tags: cmake, arm64

I have a CMakeLists.txt which works on my x64 machine but not an ARM64 machine.
The problem is this call:

```
find_library(UnitTest++ REQUIRED)
```

I can find `libUnitTest++.so` in `/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/`, but CMake doesn't find it:

```
CMake Error at test/CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_library):
  Could not find UnitTest++ using the following names:


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I have tried all sorts of fiddles, such as

```
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu)
```

Answer (score 0):

After ages I found the answer is simply to use the newer-style version of `find_library`:

```
find_library(UINTTESTPP NAMES UnitTest++ REQUIRED)
```

How annoying is that!

I hope this helps someone else with the same issue.

Comment: "use the newer-style version of `find_library`" - It is not a newer-style which fixes your problem. The original `find_library(UnitTest++ REQUIRED)` call simply misses the parameter with the library name, which has **never** work.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev. I see what I did: I changed it from `find_package` to `find_library` and didn't change the parameters. I'm wondering how my wrong version worked on x64. Although it's embarrassing, I'll leave this question here, in case someone else makes the same mistake.